# DOES GPS RECEIVER WILL HAVE ADDRESS

Tags: android

The GPS receiver in every phone have different addresses to identify uniquely
Or the every receiver works same 
I just wanted to know it

Answer (score 0):

No. Regular GPS receiver (as you have in phone or car navigation) is a passive device and as such is not sending out any data therefore there's no real need to identify it.

Comment: Can I find other GPS phone location

Answer (score -1):

**I have research about this topic and i found this article**

In this article, we'll review the basics of how cell phones and GPS receivers work. Then, we'll explore how phones combine these technologies.

**Cell Phone Basics**

A [cell phone](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cell-phone.htm) is basically a sophisticated two-way [radio](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/radio.htm). Towers and base stations, arranged into a network of cells, send and receive radio signals. Cell phones contain low-power transmitters that let them communicate with the nearest tower.

As you travel, you move from one cell to another, and the base stations monitor the strength of your phone's signal. As you move toward the edge of one cell, your signal strength diminishes. At the same time, the base station in the cell you are approaching notices the strength of your signal increasing. As you move from cell to cell, the towers transfer your signal from one to the next.

In remote locations, towers may be so far apart that they can't provide a consistent signal. Even when towers are plentiful, mountains and tall buildings can interrupt their signals. Sometimes people have a hard time getting clear signals inside buildings, especially in elevators.

Even without a GPS receiver, your cell phone can provide information about your location. A computer can determine your location based on measurements of your signal, such as:

- Its angle of approach to the cell towers
- How long it takes the signal to travel to multiple towers
- The strength of your signal when it reaches the towers

Since obstacles like trees and buildings can affect how long it takes your signal to travel to a tower, this method is often less accurate than a GPS measurement.­­

If you want to learn more about GPS : [**How GPS Receivers Work**](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/travel/gps.htm)

Comment: may i know why down wot on my answer ?